# List of client IPs and request URLs in WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

We are migrating our app from JBoss 4.2.3 to WildFly 14. In JBoss, we used "Tomcat Status" management page to see requests coming to server when server was overloaded. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvyaM.png).

Please, where could we find list of client IPs and request URLs in WildFly? Thanks!